# bash echo problem

Tags: bash, sed, echo

Here's a bash script that extracts some data from a html file.

```
price=`grep '        <td>\$' $1 | sed -e 's/<td>//g' -e 's:</td>::g' -e 's/\$ //g' -e 's/^  *//g'`
grep '        <td>\$' $1 | sed -e 's/<td>//g' -e 's:</td>::g' -e 's/\$ //g' -e 's/^  *//g'

echo "Price: $price"
```

The sed part could use some help, but that's not the issue here. The problem is that, when I run the script, it should print the found value twice, right? But it prints it only once, the first time (Without the 'Price:'). What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the string you're returning has a `\r` in it, which returns the cursor to the first column before printing stuff out. Use `od -c` to verify. And use a proper tool such as [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to make sure this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

The first grep reads everything on standard input. Then, the second grep blocks trying to read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that unlike the code shown, the assignment actually happens in a subshell and therefore is not visible (lost on exit of subshell)

I'm afraid you ran into a subshell issue that you donot show here. Post more code that you actually use if you can.

--- Sample:

```
 unset price
 price=1
 echo $price   # works

 unset price
 echo -n 1 | price=$(cat)
 echo $price   # works _not_
```

Comment: There's no more code, that's the whole script (well, the part with the variable is). It's ran on this: http://www.apparelorder.com/Productview.Asp?ProID=528844

Comment: Good. Then odds are shifting towards the '\r' hypothesis mentioned by Ignacio

Comment: PS. No need to mention which _shoes you were running on_ hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments about your use of sed:

`-e 's/^  *//g'` -- you don't need the "g": your pattern is anchored at the beginning so it can only match once. Might as well look for tabs too: `-e 's/^[[:space:]]\{1,\}//'`

`-e 's/<td>//g' -e 's:</td>::g'` can be collapsed into `-e 's|</\{0,1\}td>||g'`